# Как установить Keras и Tensorflow в R?

Tags: python, r, keras, tensorflow

Никак не получается установить Keras и Tensorflow в R 4.0.2. Нашел ресурс, где этот процесс достаточно подробно описан: https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/how-to-setup-keras-and-tensorflow-in-rstudio-on-windows-d0175e9a8f10

Дошел до пункта 3: не понимаю, где нужно вводить `pip install tensorlflow` и `pip install keras`.
В Jupyter Notebook загрузка не происходит.
В Spyder появляется текст:

```
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3267, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-1-55fe5a7ae02f>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/user/Downloads/Python.py', wdir='C:/Users/user/Downloads')

  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 704, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/user/Downloads/Python.py", line 8
    python -m pip install [tensorflow]
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где нужно вводить эти 2 команды?

Comment: Посмотрите, как установить pip. Потом запускайте из команд.строки
https://pythonru.com/baza-znanij/ustanovka-pip-dlja-python-i-bazovye-komandy

Comment: Не получается. На компьютере установлена версия python 3.6, но в командной строке при вызове `python --version` всегда появляется текст **"python" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом**

Answer (score 0):

Windows не видит Python в Вашей системе. Для начала найдите папку Python в Вашей системе. Искать нужно в проводнике. Как правило путь этой папки такой: C:\Users(ИМЯ ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36 или: C:\Python36. В крайнем случае можно написать в поиске Windows или проводника: python, и тогда система выдаст все файлы и папки, которые имеют python в своем названии. В конце концов в папке с названием той версии, которой Вы установили ранее, должен быть файл python.exe. После того, как Вы нашли его, скопируйте путь к файлу из проводника.